# How to correctly change the line in easygui's msgbox?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

When I changed the msgbox in easygui to another line, I got a str error.

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

And my code is like this.

```
import datetime,easygui
d1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 29)
d2 = datetime.datetime.now()
calc = (d1 - d2).days
last = calc+1
a = "you have",last,"days"
b = "Don't worry"
easygui.msgbox(a+'\n'+b)
```

I tried to change the last line of output code a+'\n'+b to a,'\n',B

But the output is not what I want. Easygui identifies the parameters behind the comma as the confirmation button!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this problem.
Change last line like this.

> easygui.msgbox("You have " + str(last) + " days" + "\nDon't worry", "INFO")

Comment: Actually your problem came from this: `a = "you have",last,"days"`, what defines a `tuple`. After that, you tried to add it to a `str`: `a+'\n'+b`, hence the `TypeError`.

Comment: Well, something more pythonic to achieve the same: replace the last three lines from your script (the version from the post) by `easygui.msgbox("You have {} days\nDon't worry".format(last), "INFO")`